# typescript create context default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to define setState as default value for createContext? I'm fine with createContext(null) but typescript throw error.

```
const myContext = createContext({
  isActive: false,
  setActive: (value: boolean) => {} //what to do here?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure where is the error, since I believe the `context` value is a free form object `any`.

And I copied your code into the compiler, it doesn't give me any error. So i understand what you are asking then. Yes put a default as anything is fine. The default value only give you two things.

- format of the value, easy to read for you to understand in the future
- default value if no provider is used throughout the entire app

```
  const myContext = createContext({})
```

The above line is absolutely fine if you don't want to write anything concrete.

But then when you provide it, you can put your state there.

```
  <MyContext.Provider value={useState(false)} />
```

##### typescript

If you want to enforce the type, you can do the following.

```
  const context = React.useContext(MyContext) as MyContextType
```

And define the `MyContextType` as,

```
type MyContextType = {
  isActive?: boolean,
  setActive?: (v: boolean) => void
}
```

Comment: `setActive: (v: boolean) => void` error `is declared but its value is never read.`

Comment: ok, then add an optional `?` there, i updated the post.

Comment: ok, add _ will do. like _v

Comment: sure, either way, basically make sure when you use `MyContextType`, the context conforms to the shape of your type. However if you are not using the type, nobody will care what's inside ;)